# Как из символьного потока исключить символы, попадающие под маску

Tags: java, файлы, swing, поток-ввода

Задача в следующем:

Есть панель с двумя кнопками:

1. Выбирает текстовый файл
2. Удаляет из выбранного файла неугодные данные

Создать панель с кнопками получилось, так же получилось сделать функцию, которая заменяет неугодные данные на "Обезличино". Теперь хочу с помощью `BufferedReader` прочитать выбранный файл кнопкой 1, затем используя функцию замены символов перезаписать файл обратно.
На этом месте и заглох, помогите пожалуйста.

**Выбираю файл:**

```
Chois.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
label.setText(file.getName());
```

Функция определяющая неугодные символы:

```
private static  String censorTag(final String line, final int index)
{
  if (index >= tags.length)
{
    return line;
}
else
{
   final String searchString = tags[index] + "=";
   final int start = line.indexOf(searchString);
   if (start != -1)
   {
      final int newSearchPosition = start + searchString.length();
      final int end = line.indexOf(searchString, newSearchPosition >= 
      line.length() - 1 ? line.length() -1 : newSearchPosition);
      if (end != -1)
      {
         final String cencored = new 
         StringBuffer(line).replace(start, end, "ОБЕЗЛИЧИНО").toString();
         return censorTag(cencored, index +1);
      }
      else
      {
      return censorTag(line, index +1);
      }
      }
       else {
       return censorTag(line, index +1);
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь прочесть файл выбранный:

```
JFileChooser:
final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
FileInputStream(String.valueOf(ret))));
```

Вот тут ошибка.

И затем необходимо использовать функцию замены символов:

```
final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new 
FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(ret))));
```

Comment: `Вот тут ошибка.` какая?

Comment: неправильно сформулировал мысль, хотел сказать на этот моменте я остановился, и не знаю что делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы воспользоваться функцией надо читать строки из потока в цикле:

```
  try {      
     // open input stream file for reading purpose.
     final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
     FileInputStream(file)));
     final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new 
     FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(ret))));

     while ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        writer.println(censorTag(thisLine,0));
     }       
  } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```